# Firing 2 different emails from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, automation, outlook

I am trying to fire 2 different emails from VBA and I'm getting stuck when the 2nd email pops up because recipients are not filling as desired.

I'm not very well versed in coding but have managed to put the following code together; See code below:

```
Sub Export_Mail()

Dim strFile As String
Dim OutApp As outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Recipient
Dim Recipients As Recipients

Dim strFile2 As String
Dim OutApp2 As outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg2 As outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip2 As Recipient
Dim Recipients2 As Recipients

Dim sDate

  sDate = Date

  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set objOutlookMsg = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  
  strFile = "C:\filepath\filename.xlsx" 'Directories to save and get attachments from; including filename
  strFile2 = "C:\filepath\filename2.xlsm"
  strBody = "<BODY style=font-size:10pt> Hello Customer team,<br><br>Greetings greetings<br>Attached file extract." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
  strBody2 = "<BODY style=font-size:10pt> Hello Internal team,<br><br>Greetings greetings<br>Attached full file." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFile2 'Turn alerts off to overwrite both files always
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFile
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
       
  Set Recipients = objOutlookMsg.Recipients
  Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients.Add("cust1@example.com")
  objOutlookRecip.Type = 1                                                      ' Type 1 = To; Type 2 = CC
  Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients.Add("cust2@example.com")
  objOutlookRecip.Type = 1
  Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients.Add("cust3@example.com")
  objOutlookRecip.Type = 2
  Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients.Add("cust4@example.com")
  objOutlookRecip.Type = 2
  
  With objOutlookMsg
    '.SentOnBehalfOfName = "myemail@example.net"
    .Subject = "Email Subject " & sDate
    For Each objOutlookRecip In objOutlookMsg.Recipients     'Resolve each Recipient's name.
      objOutlookRecip.Resolve
    Next
    .Attachments.Add strFile
    .display
    .HTMLBody = strBody & .HTMLBody
  End With
  'objOutlookMsg.send
  'Set OutApp = Nothing
  
  'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
  
  Set OutApp2 = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set objOutlookMsg2 = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  
  With objOutlookMsg2
    .Subject = "Internal email sibject" & sDate
    Set Recipients2 = objOutlookMsg.Recipients ' Type 1 = To; Type 2 = CC
    Set objOutlookRecip2 = Recipients2.Add("internal1@example.net")
    objOutlookRecip2.Type = 1
    Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients2.Add("internal2@example.net")
    objOutlookRecip2.Type = 1
    Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients2.Add("internal3@example.net")
    objOutlookRecip2.Type = 2
    For Each objOutlookRecip In objOutlookMsg.Recipients     'Resolve each Recipient's name.
      objOutlookRecip.Resolve
    Next
    .Attachments.Add strFile2
    .display
    .HTMLBody = strBody2 & .HTMLBody
  End With
End Sub
```

The recipients I have setup for the second email are being filled on the 1st email.
And the second email pops up with no recipients.
Any pointers on how to fix this would be of great help.

Comment: `Set Recipients2 = objOutlookMsg.Recipients` should be `Set Recipients2 = objOutlookMsg2.Recipients`  ??  Likewise `For Each objOutlookRecip In objOutlookMsg2.Recipients`

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot Tim, I was missing a lot of referencing to the second set of variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Tim Williams.

Se corrected code below

```
 Set OutApp2 = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set objOutlookMsg2 = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  
  With objOutlookMsg2
    .Subject = "Internal email subject" & sDate
    Set Recipients2 = objOutlookMsg2.Recipients ' Type 1 = To; Type 2 = CC
    Set objOutlookRecip2 = Recipients2.Add("internal1@example.net")
    objOutlookRecip2.Type = 1
    Set objOutlookRecip2 = Recipients2.Add("internal2@example.net")
    objOutlookRecip2.Type = 1
    Set objOutlookRecip2 = Recipients2.Add("internal3@example.net")
    objOutlookRecip2.Type = 2
    For Each objOutlookRecip2 In objOutlookMsg2.Recipients     'Resolve each Recipient's name.
      objOutlookRecip2.Resolve
    Next
    .Attachments.Add strFile2
    .display
    .HTMLBody = strBody2 & .HTMLBody
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to iterate over all recipients to resolve their names against the address book. The [Recipients.ResolveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipients.resolveall?view=outlook-pia) method attempts to resolve all the `Recipient` objects in the `Recipients` collection against the Address Book.

```
Sub Export_Mail()

Dim strFile As String
Dim OutApp As outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Recipient
Dim Recipients As Recipients

Dim strFile2 As String
Dim OutApp2 As outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg2 As outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip2 As Recipient
Dim Recipients2 As Recipients

Dim sDate

  sDate = Date

  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set objOutlookMsg = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  
  strFile = "C:\filepath\filename.xlsx" 'Directories to save and get attachments from; including filename
  strFile2 = "C:\filepath\filename2.xlsm"
  strBody = "<BODY style=font-size:10pt> Hello Customer team,<br><br>Greetings greetings<br>Attached file extract." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
  strBody2 = "<BODY style=font-size:10pt> Hello Internal team,<br><br>Greetings greetings<br>Attached full file." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFile2 'Turn alerts off to overwrite both files always
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFile
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
       
  Set Recipients = objOutlookMsg.Recipients
  Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients.Add("cust1@example.com")
  objOutlookRecip.Type = 1                                                      ' Type 1 = To; Type 2 = CC
  Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients.Add("cust2@example.com")
  objOutlookRecip.Type = 1
  Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients.Add("cust3@example.com")
  objOutlookRecip.Type = 2
  Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients.Add("cust4@example.com")
  objOutlookRecip.Type = 2
  
  With objOutlookMsg
    '.SentOnBehalfOfName = "myemail@example.net"
    .Subject = "Email Subject " & sDate
    
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
    
    .Attachments.Add strFile
    .display
    .HTMLBody = strBody & .HTMLBody
  End With
  'objOutlookMsg.send
  'Set OutApp = Nothing
  
  'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
  
  Set OutApp2 = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set objOutlookMsg2 = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  
  With objOutlookMsg2
    .Subject = "Internal email sibject" & sDate
    Set Recipients2 = .Recipients ' Type 1 = To; Type 2 = CC
    Set objOutlookRecip2 = Recipients2.Add("internal1@example.net")
    objOutlookRecip2.Type = 1
    Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients2.Add("internal2@example.net")
    objOutlookRecip2.Type = 1
    Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients2.Add("internal3@example.net")
    objOutlookRecip2.Type = 2
    
    Recipients2.ResolveAll
    
    .Attachments.Add strFile2
    .display
    .HTMLBody = strBody2 & .HTMLBody
  End With
End Sub
```